# Display places 2 weeks or older with Ruby on Rails + PostgresQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, view

This topic has been covered before, but I am new and trying to understand. My app is designed to store the locations of an item and since time matters, I wanted to create a link for a view that would ONLY show places that are two weeks or older. I understand I should create a method in the model similar to what's below, but I am just confused on this code. I have been trying to find material to read to understand better. The homepage shows all the places, but I want a link to also show 2 weeks or older.

Along with help, I would love any good reads to help me understand better. Thanks so much SO!

```
def self.recent_places
  Place.select("p.*, COUNT(v.id) AS count").where("post.created_at >= 2.week.ago.utc")
end
```

This is a link to the GitHub.
https://github.com/Mbartlett413/DumpStack

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using scope over class method though two are mostly the same:

```
scope :older_than, ->(time) { where("created_at < ?", time) }
```

Using:

```
Post.older_than(2.weeks.ago)
Post.older_than(1.month.ago)
```

Here you go: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments

Comment: @moveson Thank you. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just solved this for my own app, this is the method that I used inside my model:

```
scope :recent_places, -> {
  where(Place.arel_table[:created_at].lt(2.weeks.ago))
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the .arel_table and the .gt ??? The code above worked but I am always trying to learn

Comment: @MasonSB Here is a pretty good explanation: https://jpospisil.com/2014/06/16/the-definitive-guide-to-arel-the-sql-manager-for-ruby.html
Basically, arel is what sits between your pretty ruby queries, and the actual sql that is sent to the database. By accessing the arel table directly, you are querying something that has already been built, essentially putting you as close to the data as possible without writing raw sql. When using methods like 'where', it has to generate an arel table and the underlying sql for each request. 'gt' and 'lt' are 'greater than' and 'less than'.